# Is incorrect to have the HTTPS version of the sitemaps.org URL in the xmlns sitemap schema?

Tags: https, xml-sitemap, xml, namespace

I have the schema with this:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Is it correct or should be:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

if all my web pages are on HTTPS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can validate your sitemap on https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools. It will give an error when you use https to refer to the schema.

I have also seen other sitemap validators that refuse to validate the https version of the namespace, so using http might be the only correct option, even when your site only uses https.

Comment: However GSC (formerly Google Webmaster Tools) does _not_ give an error when using `https` for the sitemap namespace URI. (?)

Comment: I found an error using google webmaster tools because of the https.So I found the tool and the answer the best.

Answer (score 10):

The value of the `xmlns` attribute is to uniquely identify a namespace (the "namespace URI"). It does not relate to whether your site is serving content over HTTP or HTTPS - for this it makes no difference.

The `sitemaps.org` site defines the protocol using `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` as the recognised namespace - so this should really be the string used.

(However, `sitemaps.org` does universally redirect *everything* to HTTPS, so *maybe* both would seem to be valid? But see @unor's comment below.)

Comment: "[…] so both would seem to be valid?" -- I don’t think so. `xmlns` values act as identifiers, the URIs don’t necessarily get retrieved (which is [sometimes not even possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761004/1591669)).

Comment: Yes, it's essentially an identifier. Google accepts both, since people tend to use them interchangeably nowadays. That said, there are no HTTP or HTTPS requests made to that URL when a sitemap file is processed, so in practice it doesn't affect security at all.

Comment: This is an example of a URL used as a URN (name).   If you change it to HTTPS, it loses its defined meaning.   See [What is the difference between a URI, URL, and URN](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19101/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url/77783#77783)

Answer (score 1):

Just has similar problem with this a I want to confirm what 'DocRoot' say.
Google Search Console **did not recognize** version with 'https'
but I changed that to version with 'http' and everything works (google shows sitemap is valid)

So

**incorrect**: https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9

**correct**: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9