# HTTPS implementation. Should I change pre-head tags?

Tags: html, https

I implemented HTTPS on all the webpages of my website. My browser tells me it's a "Secure connection" with a green signal. I double-checked that all the images, CSS files, JS files, etc. were HTTPS, and I think it's everything ok.

However, I'm still using the following pre-head code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
```

Should I change this two HTTP calls from 'http' to 'https'?

Comment: Not needed since those are not external resources that the browser will download.

Comment: Is this website a CMS?

Comment: Related / duplicate(?): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108855/is-incorrect-to-have-the-https-version-of-the-sitemaps-org-url-in-the-xmlns-site

Answer (score 1):

Like Simon Hayter said, those are not links to resources but identifiers (URIs and not URLs). The browser will not fetch anything at these endpoints, and they must remain as is because they identify something special with a specific sense, and it may not work anymore if you replace `http` by `https`.

You apply the same response to basically any attribute that is `xmlns` or `xmlns:whatever`. The ns here means `namespace` which is a kind of identifier used in XML world with which HTML has ties.