# Google search console error: "Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace" when using HTTPS namespace URL

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, seo-audit

We migrated our site from HTTP to HTTPS. Then we verified our property in search console and submit the new sitemap with HTTPS URLs.

After submission it has the error "Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace."

[image]
This appears to be because we used `https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` instead of `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`. Is this really important to use the HTTP version of that URL in sitemap?   That URL is redirected to HTTPS and google is also supporting HTTPS.

Comment: The _namespace_ should be `http`, not `https`. See this related question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108855/is-incorrect-to-have-the-https-version-of-the-sitemaps-org-url-in-the-xmlns-site