# Tracking external links with internal redirect URL - best practice?

Tags: seo, redirects, links

We operate a site that lists service providers and serves as a lead generation platform for them, specifically via external links that point to our partners. (~90% of our pages contain 1-3 such external links, which we'll ultimately reduce to around ~15-30%.)

To track the clicks on these links, we currently use Google Analytics with custom Events (via JavaScript). But we want to build a custom solution in our backend so that we can easily generate performance reports for our clients.

Ideally, instead of linking to `www.ourclient.domain` directly, we'd have internal URLs like `www.ourwebsite.domain/redirect?target=www.ourclient.domain`, i.e. a redirect URL that takes the target as an HTTP GET parameter.

The question is: **What is best practice for implementing redirects to external sites, specifically from an SEO perspective?**

I've seen some sites implement this with a 307 Temporary Redirect, which seems in violation of the standard. Other sites to render a page (with a HTTP 200 status code) that contains a redirect via META tags or JavaScript.

So what is best practice? Has Google perhaps even given guidance on this?

Comment: "a 307 Temporary Redirect, which seems in violation of the standard" -- What standard would that be?   I don't know of any standard that would prevent you from implementing temporary redirects.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish as far as SEO goes?   Since these links are sponsored, I'd think that your SEO goal should be to no be penalized for selling links.

Comment: Regarding the standard: "The 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code indicates that the target resource resides temporarily under a different URI" (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.7) - 307 isn't intended for redirects to external pages, or at least that's my understanding.

Regarding our SEO goals: Yes, we want to avoid penalties for sold links. We also want to avoid penalties for a wrong implementation that might confuse Google & co. or, worst case, be interpreted as an attempt to deceive them.

Comment: "isn't for redirects to external pages"  -- What gave you that impression?   Is says that a URI can be used.  It doesn't limit it to same-host URIs or relative URIs.   Maybe you think "URI" refers to the path portion of the URL?  That is a common misconception and it is not true.  URI are a broader class of resource identifiers than URL.  See [What is the difference between a URI and a URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19101/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

Comment: Assume that `theirwebsite.domain` is the one that uses 307 redirects. The target resource `www.theirpayingclient.domain` never resided under `www.theirwebsite.domain/redirect?target=www.theirpayingclient.domain`, and other than an affiliate relationship, both websites are independent of each other. So, no, I didn't misunderstand URL/URI, but it has been my understanding that the 3xx codes are supposed to be used when actual content was moved from one place to another place; and not to send users to other websites.

Comment: Nothing in the spec prevents the creation of URLs just for the purpose of redirecting.  Since there has never been content on your `/redirect?target=site` URL, there is no expectation that it not redirect.

Comment: What strategy did you end up going with and what were the SEO implications?

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy for a redirect URL is a good one, and it will allow you to use custom GA code to report on the leads.

If your goal is to prevent link juice from passing to the advertiser's domains, here is some info:

1. 301 redirects pass link juice.
2. There is controversy as to how much
   link juice 302 redirects pass. Some sources say none, some sources
   say all, and some sources say some.
3. 307 redirects also likely pass
   link juice similarly to a 302.
4. Meta Refresh javascript likely passes
   some, but not all link juice.
5. Javascript redirects probably pass a
   little link juice.

Google Webmaster Guidelines state that you shouldn't sell followed links. As a result, you really don't want Google to be following advertiser links regardless of how you redirect to them on your website. You should be adding "nofollow" tags to these links.

If your redirect url is `www.ourwebsite.domain/redirect?target=www.ourclient.domain/page.html`, because this URL clearly isn't temporary and will never redirect to a different page, I would use a 301 permanent. If you ever have plans of redirecting `www.ourwebsite.domain/redirect?target=www.ourclient.domain/page.html` to a different page like www.ourclient.domain/page-different.html then I would use a 302 temporary.

You can also tell Google not to crawl the `?redirect` parameter at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters?hl=en&siteUrl=
Set the `Which URLs with this parameter should Googlebot crawl?` to `No Urls`